# US Permanent Resident Working From Home

Tags: working

I'm a US Permanent Resident. My job allows me to work from home full time. I want to partially move back to Honduras where I'm a citizen. I would come back to the US every couple of months for face time meetings etc...I was thinking about doing this for 1 year.

Can I do this without my employer knowing anything about it? I would VPN..take call/ confrence calls like I live in the US.

Comment: If you're asking with respect to your employer, [workplace.se] would be the better site.

Comment: Why would you *not* tell your employer about it?

Comment: You might remain resident in the US for immigration purposes, but also be resident in Honduras for tax and employment law. Your employer's HR and payroll departments really need to know where you are working to comply with all applicable laws.

Comment: Your employer might notice. If the address they think you are working at is within commuting distance of the office, they would expect you to be able to attend an afternoon face-to-face meeting that was called at 10 a.m.

Answer (score 3):

The only danger with respect to your permanent resident status would be a finding that you had abandoned your permanent residence.  If you're never outside the US for more than six months at once, and the whole arrangement lasts for no more than a year, there's no appreciable risk of that happening.